# sum up column and take it as colnames- dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

```
d <- data.frame(var1 = c(0,0,1),var2 = c(45.245,818.15,151.12),var3 = c(45,159,0),group = c('a','a','b'))
d
  var1    var2 var3 group
1    0  45.245   45     a
2    0 818.150  159     a
3    1 151.120    0     b
```

I want `d$group` to be the colnames and the former colnames (`var1`,`var2`,`var3`) to be the rownames. The values should be summed up

It should look like this

```
       a            b
var1   0             1
var2   863.395      151.12
var3   204          0
```

I tried `pivot_longer(d,cols = 'group',names_to = c('var1','var2','var3')` but I reveived Errors.

Comment: in the pivot_longer, you need `cols = -group`. After this you will need a pivot_wider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this reshaping your data and aggregating by group. You first have to summarise the values per `group` and then combine `pivot_longer()` and `pivot_wider()` to obtain the desired result. Here the code using `tidyverse` functions (I have used your `d` data):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
newd <- d %>% group_by(group) %>%
  summarise_all(.funs = sum) %>%
  pivot_longer(-group) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = group,values_from=value)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  name      a     b
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 var1     0     1 
2 var2   863.  151.
3 var3   204     0
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach would be to use `values_fn` argument to sum the values.

```
library(tidyr)

d %>%
  pivot_longer(-group, names_to = 'var', values_to = 'value') %>%
  pivot_wider(values_from = value, names_from = group, values_fn = {sum})

# var       a     b
# <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 var1     0     1 
# 2 var2   863.  151.
# 3 var3   204     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
> d1 <- as.data.frame(t(d %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(var1 = sum(var1), var2 = sum(var2), var3 = sum(var3)))[-1,])
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
> names(d1) <- c('a','b')
> d1
           a       b
var1       0       1
var2 863.395 151.120
var3     204       0
>
```

Answer (score 0):

For completion here is `data.table` method similar to @AlexB's `tidyr` approach :

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(d), id.vars = 'group'), 
      variable~group, value.var = 'value', fun.aggregate = sum)

#   variable   a   b
#1:     var1   0   1
#2:     var2 863 151
#3:     var3 204   0
```